# Install MySQLdb python module 

Tags: python, mysql

i want to install MySQLdb module for Python on Windows 7, but I get an error

```
G:\python\python and mysql\MySQL-python-1.2.3b2\MySQL-python-1.2.3b2>setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\python\python and mysql\MySQL-python-1.2.3b2\MySQL-python-1.2.3b2\set
up.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "G:\python\python and mysql\MySQL-python-1.2.3b2\MySQL-python-1.2.3b2\set
up_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, options['registry_ke
y'])
WindowsError: [Error 2]

G:\python\python and mysql\MySQL-python-1.2.3b2\MySQL-python-1.2.3b2>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/forums/forum/70460/topic/3108914) implies the problem is that you need mysql installed on the system you want to use the client libraries on, even if you don't use the server on the same system.